# Getting error : Malformed URL error in ec2

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, aws-cli, s3cmd

I am getting the error Malformed URL

```
ec2-describe-instances instance_id  xxx
Malformed URL: 'ec2.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com'
```

However, I am able to get access to the bucket through command line:

```
s3cmd  ls s3://edgeproductionlb-logs
DIR   s3://edgeproductionlb-logs/AWSLogs/
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: more like a comment, but don't have enough reputation yet: can you run verbose mode to get more info? ec2-describe-instances -v xxxx

Comment: # ec2-describe-instances instance_id  i-xxxxx -v
Setting User-Agent to [ec2-api-tools 1.6.13.0]
Malformed URL: 'ec2.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com'

Means ??

Comment: I can't reproduce on my side, with the same url you mention everything is fine... I don't know if this will resolve your problem, but as a first step you should consider to upgrade your cli (version 1.7.3.2 from my side)

Comment: # dpkg -l | grep "ec2-api-tools"
ii  ec2-api-tools                         1.6.13.0-0ubuntu1~trusty1~ppa1      all          Amazon EC2 API tools


# apt-get install ec2-api-tools 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
ec2-api-tools is already the newest version.

Comment: I never install from repo, as it is often not up to date. I get it from here: https://aws.amazon.com/developertools/Amazon-EC2/351
However this is probably not the root cause of your problem, but i got no more idea and can't reproduce this...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the Answer :

It was issue of IAM User. I created IAM user and got Access Key & 
Secret Access Key.

# ec2-describe-instances -O Access Key ID -W Secret Access Key

For Details of creating IAM-Users in AWS refer

Thank you !

http://aws.amazon.com/documentation/iam/